# Wagtail render any path in index page

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I need to enable some pages to write an arbitrary URL that does not depend on the structure of the site.

For example I have structure:

```
/
/blog
/blog/blogpost1
/blog/blogpost2
```

But, for example, I need change url from `/blog/blbogpost2` to `/some/blogpost/url1`

For this, I decided to give the opportunity to handle any URL of the main page of the site.

```
class IndexPage(RoutablePageMixin, Page):
    ...
    @route(r'^(?P<path>.*)/$')
    def render_page_with_special_path(self, request, path, *args, **kwargs):
        pages = Page.objects.not_exact_type(IndexPage).specific()
        for page in pages:
            if hasattr(page, 'full_path'):
                if page.full_path == path:
                    return page.serve(request)
        # some logic
```

But now, if this `path` is not found, but I need to return this request to the standard handler. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't possible with `RoutablePageMixin`; Wagtail treats URL routing and page serving as two distinct steps, and once it's identified the function responsible for serving the page (which, for `RoutablePageMixin`, is done by checking the URL route given in `@route`), there's no way to go back to the URL routing step.

However, it can be done by [overriding the page's `route()` method](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/pages/model_recipes.html#adding-endpoints-with-custom-route-methods), which is the low-level mechanism [used by `RoutablePageMixin`](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/44e5beb4812a1a980e800a56b8218d34b22598d7/wagtail/contrib/routable_page/models.py#L106-L121). Your version would look something like this:

```
from wagtail.core.url_routing import RouteResult

class IndexPage(Page):
    def route(self, request, path_components):
        # reconstruct the original URL path from the list of path components
        path = '/'
        if path_components:
            path += '/'.join(path_components) + '/'

        pages = Page.objects.not_exact_type(IndexPage).specific()
        for page in pages:
            if hasattr(page, 'full_path'):
                if page.full_path == path:
                    return RouteResult(page)

        # no match found, so revert to the default routing mechanism
        return super().route(request, path_components)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!